# Blender VSE is SLOW on new laptop as well as changes audio pitch after rendering

Tags: video-sequence-editor

So I've been using Blender as a video editor for a while now (with an older laptop) and it's worked fine. But on this new laptop, not only is the actual editing playback **extremely** slow and difficult to use (and sync audio with) but after rendering out a sample to check the audio sync, the audio in the VSE is now raised in pitch!?

Changing the pitch does nothing, I have to completely delete the project file and start new for it to stop doing it, only for it to do it again!

Tell me if I missed any info and I'll include it.

My new laptop: [https://www.amazon.com/Acer-Aspire-E5-574G-52QU-15-6-inch-Notebook/dp/B019G7VOSO/ref=sr_1_2?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1470591931&sr=1-2&keywords=acer+aspire+e15](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019G7VOSO)

That should be the Core i5 variant.

Thank you for any help. I'd like to get back to editing ASAP.

Comment: Although this seems a hardware specific question, here is one thing you might check: Does this occur only when on battery or is it on power supply? if it happens only on battery your laptop goes into powersaving mode and disables some of its features (switches from NVIDIA to Intel graphics, lowers processor speed...).

Comment: @metaphor_set I've tried it with both NVIDIA and Intel graphics and got the same result. Running it with the graphics card seem to give better performance in the VSE in boosts, so most of the time it's still very slow.
But I haven't been working with it unplugged at all, so it should be working at full power.